# How to add two times in string format in Oracle?

Tags: string, oracle, datetime, time, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two time strings in Oracle in the format, both HH24:MI:SS. I want to add those two and get the result in decimal (just like what we get after subtracting one datetime from another in Oracle). Any help?

Comment: decimal interms or what? hours or seconds or minutes?

Comment: in terms of all three

Comment: Adding two dates makes absolutely no sense. What result are you expecting from '12:00:00' add(+) '15:00:00' expression? Moreover, if you are planing to do date/time arithmetic, you'll need to convert your time string to date data type, using to_date() function, and as a result of that conversion the date part will be added - the first day of a current month, so the above expression becomes 01-10-2013 12:00:00 + 01-10-2013 15:00:00. This addition wont produce meaningful result. Oracle does not allow adding date to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

- split the time string into hours, minutes and seconds
- convert hours, minutes to seconds and add it all up
- convert the resulting seconds to interval type
- extract the time components from interval type in the format you want it.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/787e6/1)

```
create table mytab(
  time1_ varchar2(8),
  time2_ varchar2(8)
  );

insert into mytab values('12:30:00','05:50:55');
insert into mytab values('18:48:56','15:33:55');
```

**Query 1**:

```
with x as (
  select time1_,
         time2_,
         substr(time1_,1,2) * 3600 +
         substr(time1_,4,2) * 60   +
         substr(time1_,7,2)            as time1_secs,
         substr(time2_,1,2) * 3600 +
         substr(time2_,4,2) * 60   +
         substr(time2_,7,2)            as time2_secs
  from mytab
  ),
y as (
  select time1_,time2_,
         numtodsinterval(time1_secs + time2_secs,'second') time_intvl
from x
  )
select time1_, time2_,
       extract(day from time_intvl) days,
       extract(hour from time_intvl) hours,
       extract(minute from time_intvl) minutes,
       extract(second from time_intvl) seconds,
       extract(day from time_intvl) * 24 +
       extract(hour from time_intvl) ||':' ||
       extract(minute from time_intvl) ||':' ||
       extract(second from time_intvl) duration
from y
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/787e6/1/0)**:

```
|   TIME1_ |   TIME2_ | DAYS | HOURS | MINUTES | SECONDS | DURATION |
|----------|----------|------|-------|---------|---------|----------|
| 12:30:00 | 05:50:55 |    0 |    18 |      20 |      55 | 18:20:55 |
| 18:48:56 | 15:33:55 |    1 |    10 |      22 |      51 | 34:22:51 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
with x as (
  select time1_,
         time2_,
         numtodsinterval(
           (substr(time1_,1,2) + substr(time2_,1,2) )* 3600 +
           (substr(time1_,4,2) + substr(time2_,4,2) ) * 60  +
            substr(time1_,7,2) + substr(time2_,7,2) 
           , 'second'
           ) as time_intvl
  from mytab
  )
select time1_, time2_,
       extract(day from time_intvl) days,
       extract(hour from time_intvl) hours,
       extract(minute from time_intvl) minutes,
       extract(second from time_intvl) seconds,
       extract(day from time_intvl) * 24 +
       extract(hour from time_intvl) ||':' ||
       extract(minute from time_intvl) ||':' ||
       extract(second from time_intvl) duration
from x
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/787e6/1/1)**:

```
|   TIME1_ |   TIME2_ | DAYS | HOURS | MINUTES | SECONDS | DURATION |
|----------|----------|------|-------|---------|---------|----------|
| 12:30:00 | 05:50:55 |    0 |    18 |      20 |      55 | 18:20:55 |
| 18:48:56 | 15:33:55 |    1 |    10 |      22 |      51 | 34:22:51 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT
      ( TO_DATE ( '13:00:00',
                'HH24:MI:SS' )
       - TO_DATE ( '12:00:00',
                'HH24:MI:SS' ) )
          AS DECIMALS,
      ( TO_DATE ( '13:00:00',
                'HH24:MI:SS' )
       - TO_DATE ( '12:00:00',
                'HH24:MI:SS' ) )
      * 24
          AS HOURS,
        ( TO_DATE ( '13:00:00',
                 'HH24:MI:SS' )
        - TO_DATE ( '12:00:00',
                  'HH24:MI:SS' ) )
      * 24
      * 60
          AS MINUTES,
        ( TO_DATE ( '13:00:00',
                 'HH24:MI:SS' )
        - TO_DATE ( '12:00:00',
                  'HH24:MI:SS' ) )
      * 24
      * 60
      * 60
          AS SECONDS
FROM
      DUAL;
```

**Answer**:

```
DECIMALS            HOURS   MINUTES SECONDS
0.0416666666666667  1       60      3600
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ROUND
        (
            ( ( TO_DATE(t1, 'HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(t2, 'HH24:MI:SS') ) * 24 ) / 60 * 60
        ,   2
        ) AS t_minus
FROM
(
        SELECT  '22:10:00' AS t1
        ,       '21:05:00' AS t2
        FROM    DUAL
);
```